# Twitter search API created_at adding hours Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, search, twitter

I'm making a simple twitter feed using the twitter search API.
All is fine except that the time I get from created_at is 2 hours behind the excepted time.
The result is a string with: "Mon, 29 Apr 2013 11:29:40" (as example)

Would anyone know a good way to add 2 hours to this using javascript?
The time format is in hh:mm:ss, and I obviously don't want it to go on times such as 24:22:00 or 27:00:00.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: JavaScript has built-in date object [check it out](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: @Stasel I need the date that the user created the tweet, not a generated one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it by taking the time from the string, and then updating the hours with 2 (or setting it to the proper values when it's 22 or 23).
For the day I did exactly the same and update it to 30 when needed.
The string never changes in size so I can easily select the parts I want and change them to my liking.

Thanks everyone for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

The crude javascript to do this is:

```
var dateTime = new Date("Mon, 29 Apr 2013 11:29:40");

var year = dateTime.getFullYear();
var month = dateTime.getMonth();
var date = dateTime.getDate();
var hours = dateTime.getHours();
var minutes = dateTime.getMinutes();
var seconds = dateTime.getSeconds();
var milliseconds = dateTime.getMilliseconds();

hours = hours + 2;

var dateTime2 = new Date(year, month, date, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

You could then output the date with:

```
    dateTime2.toLocaleString()
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a timezone issue. If you just add two hours, then your code won't work for users in a different timezone than you. The Javascript `Date` object has a `getTimezoneOffset()` method that can help you.

Comment: Ok but i'm not using the Date object, I am literally just getting a string that looks like so: Mon, 29 Apr 2013 11:29:40

Comment: Right, but you can determine the timezone of the string you are receiving (it's two timezones west of your location). Then you can get a Date object and find that Date's timezone. From there, you can compare the Date object's timezone to the (constant) timezone of the date you are receiving, and then add or subtract hours based on that.